# UHV chamber starts oscillating once the pressure gets down to $2.5 \times 10^{-5}$, Why?

Tags: pressure, vacuum, experimental-technology

Using a new Edwards nXDS15iC scroll pump as a roughing pump for a new Kurt Lesker EMT3304 turbo pump. Chamber is a cylinder about $100{\textrm{ ft}^3}$. We have identified leaks and corrected using a helium detector. When we start approaching the $10^{-6}$ range the vacuum starts widely oscillating. We cannot find any serious leaks, The magnetron vacuum gauge is new and has a recent NIST calibration. What else could cause this problem?

Comment: The oscillating is a bit unusual, but 2E-5 Torr and 2E-6 Torr are well known 'barriers' to pump down, representing water vapor and adsorbed water on surfaces. I presume you have crossed over to the turbo pump. What is in the chamber?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "wildly oscillating"? What amplitude and frequency?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give an answer and not a comment but:

I've seen such oscillation before when pumping/venting chambers using a turbo pump attached to the chamber. It's likely some mechanical resonance that the turbo pump fan rotation is hitting when the chamber gets to a certain pressure. I think the pump rotation speed may depend on the vacuum pressure. I doubt mechanical resonances change frequency much with vacuum pressure.

You can consider how the parts of the chamber including the pumps are mechanically clamped to whatever is holding them.

Also it might be fine. You say "widely oscillating". It's hard to tell from that comment if it's actually ok, even if it's loud, and will get better when the pressure gets lower (and the fan speeds up?) and isn't a problem.

Comment: In the -5s I would expect the turbo to be at full rotation speed without any issues.